# Python- delete items of list

Tags: python, list

Sorry for a lot of questions, that is my code so far, Im not exactly sure how to remove values greater .

compute average of the values in the list and removes all values greater than the average from given list

```
n = int(input("Number of values in list: "))
numbers = []
average=0
for i in range(n):
    lists = float(input("Enter a floating number: "))
    numbers.append(lists)
    average=average+ lists/n

print (numbers)
if lists>average
value = numbers.pop
```

thank you :)

Comment: is floating numbers are input from the command line?

Comment: I have a small question, how would I be able to remove the "lists" from the numbers list if the average of the list is greater than some of the numbers from the list, hopefully that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for my understanding, you just want a list of numbers, then remove all the numbers which bigger than the average? you can just filter the numbers not bigger than average.

```
n = int(input("Number of values in list: "))
numbers = []
average=0
for i in range(n):
    lists = float(input("Enter a floating number: "))
    numbers.append(lists)
    average=average+ lists/n

print (numbers)

# filter numbers not greater than average, and get a new list
numbers = [n for n in numbers if n <= average]
print (numbers)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
response = raw_input('Enter floats separated by spaces')
float_list = map(float, response.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b= []
c= [4.5,3.4,3.141592654]
def func(a):
        for numbers in a:
            b.append(numbers)
func(c)
```

Not sure if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it using this method, thank you for the help

```
n = int(input("Number of values in list: "))
numbers = []
average=0
for i in range(n):
    lists = float(input("Enter an float: "))
    numbers.append(lists)
    average=average+ lists/n
print(numbers)
```

Comment: You are using Python 3, right? The code would be different, for Python 2 (no need for `int()` and `float()`, or, better, `raw_input()` instead of `input()`).